No wifi driver for RT5370 Wireless Adapter in 22.04
Ubuntu 22.04 on Orange Pi 5 board. There is no wireless interface after I insert WiFi USB adapter. The output:
$ lsusb 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13ba:0018 PCPlay Barcode PCP-BCG4209
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ modinfo rt2800usb | grep 5370

$ uname -a
Linux user-desktop 5.10.160-rockchip #26 SMP Thu Dec 21 14:15:31 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

But it was there according to Debian wiki.
Why the support of RT5370 was dropped and how to enable it?

You should probably ask the people that made that kernel as the 5370 is still supported in Ubuntu kernels

OK, I'll ask those ppl. But who knows, may be someone here knows the answer too.

There was issue in kernel. It was fixed by Joshua Riek in kernel 6.1.0-1017.
$ uname -a
Linux user-desktop 6.1.0-1017-rockchip #17-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 23 19:14:56 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux      

$ modinfo rt2800usb | grep 5370
alias:          usb:vF201p5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*


Not a supported kernel in Ubuntu.
